# Code not reaching the end of try block, but not reaching catch block either?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to connect to a Socket and I've been greeted with a rather strange error. For the first time this method gets called it will run fine, if the server ungracefully closes or disconnects this client then the next time this code gets ran it won't tell me if it successfull or failed?

I've ran it in debug mode and it doesn't get to the log in the try block, neither does it get to the `throw` or log in the catch block, what is happening here?

I know my log method works as it runs perfectly fine the first time running this code.

```
try
{
    _socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port));
    CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Successfully established a connection to the server.");
}
catch (SocketException socketException)
{
    if (socketException.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionRefused)
    {
        CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Failed to establish a connection with the server.");
        _reconnect = true;
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I also have a finally block, but I don't think that's anything to do with this error.

```
finally
{
    if (_socket.Connected && CoreUtilities.IsConnected(_socket))
    {
        _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnIncomingData, _socket);
        Send(new SocketPasswordComposer(_session.ConfigHandler["server.password"]));
    }

    if (!_hasConnected)
    {
        var timer = new Timer
        {
            Interval = 10000
        };

        timer.Elapsed += ElapsedTimer;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    _hasConnected = true;
}
```

Comment: You're catching one specific exception. Probably what's thrown is something different.

Comment: try removing the try/catch for now to see what exception it is that you're getting. Most likely it's not a SocketException which is why it's not being caught.

Comment: maybe the exception that is thrown is not a SocketException... This would explain this behavior. Try to add also a block to catch a general exception and see what happens

Comment: I've added a catch for the general exception, I also had it trycatching further down the call stack so I was covered. No exceptions get thrown, its just strange that it only does this after the first call to the method. The way I am testing things is: Open client, fails to connect as I haven't opened the server yet, open the server and it connects, (both of these log), after the server and client have successfully connected I close the server ungracefully, this forces a reconnection, next time the method is called it doesn't log anything and doesn't reach the end of the try or start of catch.

Comment: It just continues to reconnect like it can't connect, but without alerting us with the failed log message.

Comment: Is there anything in your Output Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Nothing that is relevant. The error isn't with LogToConsole as if that was the case the socket would connect and I know see it in the server side code, it would just skip the logging on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Do not concatenate statements or attempt specific error handling until your code is error free.

```
int step = 0;
try
{
    step = 1;
    var parsed = IPAddress.Parse(host);
    step = 2;
    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(parsed, port);
    step = 3;
    _socket.Connect(endpoint);
    step = 4;
    CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Successfully established a connection to the server.");
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "Step " + step.ToString());
}
```

If you get a Message Box showing "Step 4", the problem is with that custom **CoreUtilities.LogToConsole** code that you are not showing the code to.

Comment: The error isn't with LogToConsole as if that was the case the socket would connect and I know see it in the server side code, it would just skip the logging on the client side.

Comment: @user692959239 - still, by adding the `int step` variable, you will see in the **MessageBox** how far into the process you got.

Answer (score 0):

You're catching one specific exception. Probably what's thrown is something different. Add something like this after the catch block:

```
catch (Exception otherException)
{
   CoreUtilities.LogToConsole(otherException.Message);
   ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(otherException).Throw(); // this is better than just "throw;"
}
```

Comment: What if his `CoreUtilities.LogToConsole` method is throwing the error?

Comment: The error isn't with LogToConsole as if that was the case the socket would connect and I know see it in the server side code, it would just skip the logging on the client side.

Comment: How is using `ExceptionDispatchInfo` in this way any different than just calling `throw`?

Answer (score 0):

Possible, As you are catching only exception of type SocketException, if there is any other type of exception that is being raised, it will not get caught.

Comment: I've tried with type `Exception` and the error still isn't thrown.